# How to put an arbitrary big tuple in pattern matching with case?

Tags: scala, stream

I posted this day some questions at Stack Overflow, but the problem I am dealing with requires more complicated code than expected.

I have this code:

```
val nsc1= Stream.iterate((1,0,1,1))({case (a,b,c,d) => (b,c,d,b+c)}) map (c=> c._1)
```

Here the initial value of the stream is a Tuple4, but I need to manage an arbitrary size of it. The problem isn't actually the initial argument, but 'case' with a list of values in the tuple. How can I achieve it?

I will search on the web in 'pattern matching' also, and put the answer here if I find it.

Comment: What about List instead of Tuple?

Comment: Yes,  all of you are right, and I realized the correct way is to use for example Arrays. But anyway I like the answer giving the methods available to work on tuples.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Working with a `List` or some other type of collection would certainly be easier, but if you *really* are stuck with tuples of various lengths then I think you'll have to drop pattern matching.

Instead, you might have to pass the tuple `t =>` and then use `t.productArity`, `t.productElement()`, and/or `t.productIterator` to inspect the tuple and build the return tuple of the same profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an arbitrary length matching `List`. Not sure what you are trying to do but here is one way to do this:

```
Stream.iterate( List(1,0,1,1) ){ 
    case List(a,b,c,d) => List(b,c,d,b+c)
    case List(a,b,c) => List(a)
    case List(a,b) => List(a)
    case List(a) => List(a)
} map(_(0))
```